# Create columns which is all the other columns, for each unique value in a specific column

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have the following dataframe

```py
date    | car | cost | rev
--------+-----+------+-----
20200801  fiat   20    30
20200801  vw     10    15
20200802  fiat   21    29
20200802  audi   30    50
```

I would like to have a dataframe where each `date` only exists once and then the information for all the cars as columns e.g

```py
date    | cost_fiat | cost_audi | cost_vw | rev_fiat |  rev_audi  | rev_vw|
--------+-----------+-----------+---------+----------+------------+-------+
20200801     20        Null          10        30         Null      15
20200802     21        30            Null      29         50        Null
```

I can do it by a lot of if/else, apply, groupby etc. but I wonder if there's a function in pandas that could do some of the "heavy" calculations.

Comment: `df.pivot('date','car',['cost','rev'])` after pivoting use `df.columns=[f"{x}_{y}" for x,y in df]`

Comment: have a look at https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html

Comment: also if you think the question is wrongly closed then pls feel free to comment **:)**